# Cypress: want to partially mock XHR response

Tags: cypress, stubbing, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress and I want to stub the XHR response ***partially***. I want to catch the original JSON, and edit it partially.

for instance:

`` cy.route('GET', `**/subjects`, 'fixture:mySubjects.json'); ``

this way i am stubbing the whole response, but I want to see:

original XHR response (of course with many other properties) :

```
{ 
'id': 12345, 
"subjects": [
    {
      "key": "mat",
      "name": "maths",
      "hasAccess": true,
    },
    {
      "key": "eng",
      "name": "english",
      "hasAccess": false,
    }
  ],
}
```

what I want to stub is only name, and want to get:

```
{ 
'id': 12345, 
"subjects": [
    {
      "key": "mat",
      "name": "maths",
      "hasAccess": true,
    }
  ],
}
```

In short, what I wanted to do is to remove the second subject 'eng' from the response. any idea is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [cy.intercept()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Intercepting-a-response).

I don't quite understand what parts of the real response you want to return or stub, but this is the mechanism to do so.

```
cy.intercept('/integrations', (req) => {
  // req.reply() with a callback will send the request to the destination server
  req.reply((res) => {
    // 'res' represents the real destination response
    // you can manipulate 'res' before it's sent to the browser
  })
})
```

If you are using a Cypress version < 6 you can try using `cy.route2()` with the same syntax.

Comment: yes I am in v 5.6.0. Will try and post the outcome too. Thanks. What I wanted to do is to remove the second subject 'eng' from the response.

Comment: I have found this. Application of your solution. again thanks. Posting link for others.:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/stubbing-spying__intercept/cypress/integration/stub-fetch-spec.js